# What's the linguistic term for adding （笑）at the end of a sentence?

Tags: casual

It seems that expressions like （笑）, （大嘘）and （即答）are often added at the end of a sentence to indicate or modify the emotion. Is there a specific term for this phenomenon?

e.g.

A: 俺は休みだけど、友達とライブに行くんだ。それがすごく楽しみでさ！

B: ちょっと羨ましいな（笑）

Comment: @A.Ellett do you have an example of a dictionary that includes a "term for this phenomenon" along with the definition of, say, 大噓? That's just a normal word in its own right, so I don't know that dictionaries are going to comment on its use as an appended modifier.

Comment: @Leebo I guess I've always understood these words at face value.  I've never considered that they might have other connotations.  My bad.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the answer would be something like a linguistic term. Like how "tag question" is the answer to the question "what is the term for the phenomenon of adding "isn't it?" to the end of a sentence." As opposed to something about the meaning of "isn't it". But maybe the questioner can expand on it.

Comment: @Leebo Yeah, that's exactly what I want to ask:)

Comment: @Leebo I see what you're saying. I guess I just see these as being used like emojis (non-ironically a loan-word from Japanese) in English.  Or like "lol" etc.

Comment: And also something like wwww

Comment: Linguistically, expressions like `(笑)`, `LoL` and `*sigh*` seem to be types of *discourse markers* or *pragmatic markers*, but I could not find anything more specific than this. Or do you just want to know how ordinary people call them in general?

Comment: @naruto I think *pragmatic markers* is specific enough for me! I asked this question because I wanted to collect these expressions and maintain a database for text normalization. But I had no idea how to call and search them in a right way.

Comment: I have [this table] (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Types-of-pragmatic-markers-adapted-from-Carter-McCarthy-2006-p-208_tbl1_285169640) adapted from Cambridge Grammar of English. I'm not sure if this characteristic sets them apart, but I do note that these are particular to written language (and when reading written language aloud). I would think this might put them together with symbol, punctuation, or emoji. Are they the same part of speech as ":-)" (^_^;)?

Answer (score 1):

For （笑）, as an interjection, it would be similar to "lol." Or we could consider the character「笑」as reduced to a symbol for laughter. However, （大嘘）and （即答）are nouns in parenthesis. We could consider them as parenthetical phrases such as "His excuse was food poisoning, a big lie."